# Struggling to handle emoji in tweepy script due to encoding issues

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-2.x, tweepy

This is killing me and I'm really struggling with it... but I have a utf-8 related issue with Python.

Essentially I am trying to pull stuff from csv files to tweet. Sometimes that involves picking from a column of emoji as so:

```
t4 = function(random_line_from_csv_column_with_emoji)

tweet = t1.decode('utf-8') + " " + t2.decode('utf-8') + " " + t3.decode('utf-8') + " " + t4.decode('utf-8')

return tweet
```

Then another file uses the tweepy streaming api to pull the tweet from the module with the code above, and do a status update e.g.

```
chatResponse = get_the_tweet_above(options)
replyText = '@' + screenName + ' ' + chatResponse
twitterApi.update_status(status=replyText)
```

Most of the time, my code works... but sometimes it fails due to encoding issues, e.g.:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\U0001f63a' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\U0001f943' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Those are emoji, the smiling cat face and some clinking glasses or a tumbler or something...

Basically, I am tearing my hair out now to try and work out how to stop this from happening. I *always* run into encoding issues in Python and have never got my head around it.

If anyone can make this work with some quick and easy answer I'd be so happy!

Comment: Does `twitterApi.update_status` expect a Unicode text string or does it expect UTF-8 bytes? You may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: A string is fine. All (I think) that I need to know is how an emoji should be pulled from the csv to a variable with the correct use of .encode / .decode / etc.

Comment: I assume your CSV file is encoded in UTF-8. And I assume that "A string is fine" means that `twitterApi.update_status` can accept a Unicode string for the `status` arg. So open the CSV in binary mode, read the data, decode it from UTF-8 to Unicode, grab the stuff you want from that Unicode, and join it into the desired `status` string. Be careful not to join UTF-8 bytes with the Unicode strings, or Python 2 will "helpfully" treat the UTF-8 as ASCII and try to convert it to Unicode; that process will fail if the UTF-8 contains any non-ASCII bytes.

Comment: So, this is pretty weird but I discovered that the script works when I run it manually but fails when I run it through cronjob due to encoding. After removing a line that prints the tweet it now works both manually and on cronjob... this is weird though... how can a script run on the same server with the same python capacity fail to print UTF-8 stuff in the output when run on cronjob but not if I run it manually when logged in with SSH? It doesn't make sense to me why this would affect anything any different, but nevertheless, now everything works that I removed print of the tweet w/emoji

Comment: Here's a little test that may help explain why your cronjob is having problems. Assuming your terminal is set to use UTF-8, the following command should print `A®Z`. 1 `python2 -c "print 'A\xc2\xaeZ'"` 2 `python2 -c "print 'A\xc2\xaeZ'" | cat` 3 `python2 -c "print 'A\xc2\xaeZ'.decode('utf8')"` But this will raise `UnicodeEncodeError` 4 `python2 -c "print 'A\xc2\xaeZ'.decode('utf8')" | cat`

Comment: You're correct that 4 raises the error (thanks for the comment!), but what does that tell me? Sorry to not understand...

Comment: `print` will happily print encoded bytes to a terminal, or to a pipe / file. But if you give it unencoded Unicode to print it has to encode it first, and the encoding it uses for pipes & files may not be the same as what it uses for the terminal. Terminal encoding uses the encoding from sys.getdefaultencoding  but file encoding uses locale.getpreferredencoding